# Divide image to blocks

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N1T7E.jpg)Hi I want to divide an image (200x200) into 100 blocks of equal sizes and then I want to find average of each block. I have looked around a lot on how to divide the image into 10x10 blocks(10 rows 10 columns) but not able to grasp the concept on how to do so. Can anyone help.

Answer (score 3):

I'll assume you have numpy, since you have it as a tag. If you don't have the Pillow module, run

```
pip install Pillow
```

and grab that. The following code will split the image into a 400 blocks of 10x10.

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

image = Image.open("your_file.jpg", "r")
arr = np.asarray(image)
arr = np.split(arr, 20)
arr = np.array([np.split(x, 20, 1) for x in arr])
```

Then, to grab the i-j'th block, index into it via:

```
arr[i][j]
```

Comment: Is it possible to get the average of each block?

Comment: arr[i][j].matrix.mean() should do the trick. @ChristinaEvans

Comment: it gives an error that j is not defined

Comment: Try [arr[i][j].matrix.mean() for i in range(40) for j in range(40)]

Comment: It gives an error 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'matrix'

Comment: Oops, try [arr[i][j].mean() for i in range(40) for j in range(40)]

Comment: Thanks a lot. You are a life savor @Daniel

Comment: I have one more small question. Since we have 400 blocks shouldn't there be 400 mean values? I found the mean of each block and it shows that the length is 1600.

Comment: Yeah, my original post had an error. The 40 in my previous comments should be changed to a 20 with the updated code. My apologies.